# $L_{loc}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\not\subset\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$

Tags: distribution-theory

I am looking for an example of a function $f \in L_{loc}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ which does not induce a tempered distribution, where $L_{loc}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n}):= \{f $ measurable, $ \int_{K} \|f(x)\| < \infty  $ for all compact $ K \subset \mathbb R^n \} $

Comment: $e^{x^2} \not \in S'(\mathbb{R})$ because $\langle e^{x^2},e^{-x^2} \rangle = \infty$.

Comment: how do I see that $e^{x^2}$ is locally compact?

Comment: @Pazu: It is continuous. Continuos functions on compact sets are bounded. Compact sets have finite measure. Continuous functions are measurable. :) Also, you probably mean locally integrable, not locally compact.

Comment: @PhoemueX You are right! Thx

Comment: Bonus question : can you construct a Schwartz function such that $\langle e^{|x|}, \varphi \rangle = \infty$ ?